# Trying to access @property attribute in UINavigationcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

Have created an attribute property in TableView1.h and pushing that attributes value to another view name TableView2. How can I access the Start attribute property in another view name TableView2.m.

In TableView1.h

```
  @interface TableView1 : UIViewController{
    NSString *Start;
 }

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Start;
```

In TableView1.m

```
@synthesize Start;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
TableView2 *view2 = [[[TableView2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableView2" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease] ;
view2.Start = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[appDelegate.navController pushViewController:view2 animated:YES];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: why do u tag this with "uinavigationbar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not define property Start in TableView1

In TableView2.h

```
@interface TableView2 : SomeViewController {
  NSString * start;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * start;
...
```

In TableView2.m

```
@synthesize start;
```

In TableView1.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   TableView2 *view2 = [[[TableView2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableView2" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease] ;

   view2.start = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   [appDelegate.navController pushViewController:view2 animated:YES];
   [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

In TableView2.m just access `self.start`

Comment: do you think there is a better way to do it ? because I was told that I can do it by using @property method.

Comment: sorry, i misinterpreted your question.

Comment: actually, I am confused with the names you have typed. Is ViewList same as ListView and whats startViewController in startViewController.listView = view.

Comment: Hi Zhang. Sorry for the confusion.I am actually lost in the naming convention it seems you have got it little incorrect. I have updated my code with good naming convention.

Comment: So is your didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method in TableView1 or TableView2? also delegate.Start wont work.

Comment: thanks Zhang for clarifying. But have you checked anytime that if NSString *startString = delegate.Start; will work ? and what is delegate in your code. is it the delegate of the main file like appDelegate of my code ?

Comment: so how will I get the Start value then ? I will get "some value". have u ever tried such things b4 ?

Comment: You need to set TableView1.Start value before you init view2. If you need different Start value, perhaps you need to access self.view1.Array.

Comment: NSString *startString = self.view1.Start; gives null values. any idea yet over this ??

Comment: That means you havent set view1.Start yet. If that property is for all cells of tableview1, you can set it in -viewDidLoad of tableview1.

Comment: how do you set it in viewDidLoad?

Comment: for tableview1: `-(void)viewDidLoad {self.Start=@"some string";}`

Comment: Hello Zhang. You have not understood my question yet. I have no idea where are we leading this.I am trying to get the value from  view2.Start = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; and send it to the next view. We do get the value here without doing any set of the start variable. and no constant values anywhere else there is not use of passing the values.

Comment: Zhang you finally got that correct !!! thanks for ur patience !!! ill add as many stars as u want !!!

Comment: Hello Zhang. Thanks so much for the answer. But I have another small quick question. how can I pass this self.Start to my singleton class ?